# Laravel email not sended but no error, with own smtp server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

ISo i have a SMTP Server come with the hosting server, already use the host, port, username, password, etc correctly. The email is sending, but returns no error. Its working in mailtrap. I use beautymail for sending the email. The configuration is correct based on my cpanel site.

My `.env`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.(myweb).com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=cs@(myweb).com
MAIL_PASSWORD=(mypass)
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@(myweb).com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=(myname)
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

My mail.php file (might be usefull?)

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Mailer
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default mailer that is used to send any email
| messages sent by your application. Alternative mailers may be setup
| and used as needed; however, this mailer will be used by default.
|
*/

'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mailer Configurations
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure all of the mailers used by your application plus
| their respective settings. Several examples have been configured for
| you and you are free to add your own as your application requires.
|
| Laravel supports a variety of mail "transport" drivers to be used while
| sending an e-mail. You will specify which one you are using for your
| mailers below. You are free to add additional mailers as required.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
|            "postmark", "log", "array"
|
*/

'mailers' => [
    'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', null),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'transport' => 'ses',
    ],

    'mailgun' => [
        'transport' => 'mailgun',
    ],

    'postmark' => [
        'transport' => 'postmark',
    ],

    'sendmail' => [
        'transport' => 'sendmail',
        'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    ],

    'log' => [
        'transport' => 'log',
        'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
    ],

    'array' => [
        'transport' => 'array',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Markdown Mail Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
| theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
| of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
|
*/

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

];
```

Been searching around but nothing working for me, thankyou...

Outgoing Server (SMTP): mail.(myweb).com
with Port: 465

EDIT: Additional info, everything works when i manually set the email in outlook. The email is sended, and the inbox works properly. And some info might be usefull below

```
Username:   cs@(myweb).com
Password:   Use the email account’s password.
Incoming Server:    mail.(myweb).com
IMAP Port: 993 POP3 Port: 995

Outgoing Server:    mail.(myweb).com
SMTP Port: 465
```

Comment: remove `MAIL_MAILER` and change `MAIL_ENCRIPTION` to `tls`, then clear `php artisan config:clear` and try

Comment: When change the encryption to tls, it returns tcp://mail.(myweb).com timeout error

Comment: Can you tell me what's your outgoing `MAIL_HOST` of your live setting and also are you using secure or unsecure setting ?

Comment: Im using secure setting, the panel use 465 for secure setting

Comment: No i mean to say check your outgoing mail in your live server mail setting, wether it is `mail.myweb.com` or simple `myweb.com` ?

Comment: Its mail.myweb.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you are using secure mail setting then try this**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.(myweb).com //MAIL_HOST=myweb.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=cs@(myweb).com
MAIL_PASSWORD=(mypass)
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

**Don't forget to clear config cache `config:clear` after making changes in your `.env`**

*If your secure setting has outgoing mail server is only `myweb.com` then your `MAIL_HOST` will become `MAIL_HOST=myewb.com` the rest of your setting is fine, but also make sure to wait for 10 to 15 minutes for incoming mail in your inbox.*

Comment: The outgoing server is mail.myweb.com too

Comment: I have used this setting yesterday for my mail using ssl secure connection, and it is working. After confirming on my side I have given you this code brother.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved!**

After long discussion with my hosting support, the main problem is that i use different email address when sending the email. The email address is supposed to be same as the SMTP username (cs@myweb.com)

Before

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{
    $beautymail = app()->make(Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
    $beautymail->send('email.welcome', [], function($message)
    {
        $message
            ->from('bar@example.com')
            ->to('emailto@gmail.com', 'Customer Test')
            ->subject('Welcome!');
    });

});
```

To

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{
    $beautymail = app()->make(Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
    $beautymail->send('email.welcome', [], function($message)
    {
        $message
            ->from('cs@myweb.com')
            ->to('emailto@gmail.com', 'Customer Test')
            ->subject('Welcome!');
    });

});
```

You can refer to @Akhtar Munir answer for SMTP Setting in .env

Thank you for all your replies guys. Appreciate it.